# Removing existing backup layers and renaming current live layer in ArcSDE

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, layers, data-backup, remove

Looking at the attached screenshot of Catalog, there are the file "CRT_CANAL" and many backups. The aim of this code is deleting old backups in the ArcSDE database,
renaming the existing "CRT_CANAL" as backup + the current date (es CRT_CANAL_bck20151222) and copying the new layer in the database that will get the original name "CRT_CANAL" without date.

Running my code I got a generic error in the deleting layers section. So that the machine overcomes that part of the code and goes to the next stage renaming current live layer.

This is the message I get:

"delete old backup layer ERROR: "

without any other specification of the kind of error

This is the code:

```
                if featCount > 0:
                    sde_Connection = "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog\GISAdmin DC to GISTest.sde\GISTest.GISADMIN."
                    layer_sde_output = sde_Connection + wfsOutputName
                    layer_bck_delete = sde_Connection + wfsOutputName + "_bck*"
                    layer_bck = sde_Connection + wfsOutputName + "_bck" + strftime("%Y%m%d")
                    data_type = "FeatureClass"   

                    # Check if backup layer exists in SDE and remove it
                    if arcpy.ValidateTableName(layer_bck_delete):
                        try:
                            fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(layer_bck_delete)
                            for fc in fcList:
                                data_type = "FeatureClass"
                                arcpy.Delete_management(fc, data_type)
                                if debugMode:
                                    msg = msg + "delete old backup layer success" + "\n"
                        except:
                            msg = msg + "delete old backup layer ERROR: " +  arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
                            process = 0

                    if arcpy.Exists(layer_sde_output):
                        if process == 1:
                            # Rename current live layer
                            try:
                                arcpy.Rename_management(layer_sde_output, layer_bck, data_type)
                                if debugMode:
                                    msg = msg + "create backup layer success" + "\n"
                            except:
                                msg = msg + "create backup layer ERROR: " +  arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
                                process = 0

                    if process == 1:
                        # Import into SDE
                        try:
                            sdeLayer = sdeConnection + sdeOwner + wfsOutputName
                            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(gdbLayer, sdeLayer)
                            if debugMode:
                                msg = msg + "SDE import success" + "\n"
                        except:
                            msg = msg + "SDE import ERROR: " +  arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
                            process = 0
```

Anyone can help me in correcting this code?

Comment: Why not copy the existing layer to a new timestamped table, truncate the base table, and append the new file to the still-existing layer?  That would be using the database in best-practice fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the function ListFeatureClasses() requires a well defined environment where to list all the items I had to explicit it:

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog\GISAdmin DC to GISTest.sde"

and I changed the variable name

layer_bck_delete =  "GISLive.GISADMIN." + wfsOutputName + "_bck*"